What does "record" mean in this context? "highest" as an adjective or "to document" as a verb?
What does "record" mean in this context? "highest" as an adjective or "to document" as a verb?
"The mean maximum dispersal distance was an estimate of the distance within which most (usually> 90%) of the animals were caught. For many species, I found data for only a few individuals and used these values if they seemed reasonable. I used data primarily on dispersal of juveniles from the natal site and only used adult dispersal data when those of juveniles were not available. I did not use dispersal data from translocated animals or record dispersal distances. For some species, such as mountain goats, bighorn sheep, and sea otters, I obtained only total lifetime movements of animals and used these distances. Body masses for mammals were obtained from Eisenberg (1981), Chapman and Feldhammer (1982), and Silva and Downing (1995). If available, I used the masses as reported by Van Vuren (1998)".

I did not ... record dispersal distances. Verb meaning to document.

Dear @Michael Harvey Thank you so much for the answer.

It's a verb usage - linked back to earlier did not use through conjunction or. The writer did not use [this] or record [that]. There is no verb form of record relevant to the noun / adjective usages in breaking the record by finishing in record time.

Dear @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for the clarification and additional example.

It's not really an "additional" example - it's the same example. I just replaced "dispersal data from translocated animals" by this and "dispersal distances" by that so you could see the "parallel construction" (I did not verb OR verb)  more clearly.

I meant "breaking the record by finishing in record time". as the additional (supplementary) example.

Record is used as a verb meaning to document or notate. So when he says "I did not record dispersal distances," it means he didn't notate or save the dispersal distances during the experiment.
